# Samba reload on new dhcp lease

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, samba

I have a phone tethered via usb. I'm using the phone's data connection. Whenever I run dhclient for the new lease ( NetworkManager is off ) I get error messages but the lease succeeds. Here is the output.

```
root@roni# dhclient usb0
smbd.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "reload" failed.
```

My question is why does dhclient reload Samba after every new lease?

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for a similar problem, I have samba running on enp2s0 (LAN static IP) whenever dhclient renews my WAN enp1s0 it restarts samba and disrupts LAN shares, this would be required if samba was listening on the nic that just got renewed if the IP changed or after a reboot to bind samba to newly obtained IP, but for me it is not necessary so I have just edited `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/samba` and commented the near to last line...

```
#[ -x /etc/init.d/smbd ] && /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d smbd reload
```